# Подсветка синтаксиса PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, оформление

Python PyCharm подсвечивает только слова типа `if`, `for` все остальное остается просто белым (названия методов, `self`). Тема:"Darcula". В настройках типов файлов для питона установлены файлы расширения: (`.py`, `.pyw`)

Answer (score 1):

В Англо-нетах часто пишут: Нужно установить корневую папку проекта так, что бы файл кода был в ней. Не мой случай, мне помогло снятие галки с пункта `File Menu -> Power Saver Mode`